# How do I stitch multiple photos together to create necklace structure with imagemagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I want create necklace like structure by stitching images together with image magick, how can I achieve this?

We are using PHP to call imagemagick.

Attaching image here...
These small nuts will be separate images[image]

Comment: What exactly is a "necklace like structure"? You should post an example of what you want.

Comment: Sorry Bonzo, added image. These nuts will be individual images, I want to connect these nuts to create a necklace like displayed in image.

Answer (score 1):

1/ Resize, crop and mask your images - round image on transparent background.

2/ Assuming you always have the same amount of images; work out the positions and composite your images into the position on the blank canvas.

There is a lot more you can do like adding drop shadows or adding a glossy button finish etc.

Stackoverflow is not here to provide code for you but to help you with any code you have. You can find a lot of examples here: https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/ and they will all work with php and exec()

Comment: Hey Bonzo, Thank you for your answer. Had second option in mind just wanted to be sure whether I am going on right direction instead of doing many alteration. wanted to use experts experience. Your comments are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it logically by using individual nuts and putting them all on main image again by adjusting the left and top of each nut.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score -1):

See how you want to synthesize, the basic can use the PHP image processing function to create a canvas, the length of the three pictures of a long, width is the width of the three pictures together

Comment: Middle use the white images